# What are "tzon" in the parsha of korbanos?

Tags: animals, korban, temple-service-avoda, parashat-vayikra

Korbanos of the "tzon" variety may be brought from the "kevasim" and "izim" type. I'm wondering if there are any essays out there that identify what a "keves" and "aiz" is. I understand the common English translation of "sheep" and "goat," but I'm looking for a more precise definition. For example, the [dall sheep](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dall_sheep) is native to North America and likely was never seen by a Jew  through the times of the Bais Hamikdash. Is it a bona fide tzon?